# Maven assembly plugin creating the extra directory

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have defined a maven assembly plugin for packaging and creating the binaries in a directory other than my project directory..
pom and the assembly.xml is as follows..

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                <finalName>Simple-Batch</finalName>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../Server-Dist/target/Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bin/Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/modules/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Assembly.xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:zip</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*:zip</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.conf</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

But the problem is,
the created folder structure is
target\Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\modules\Simple-Batch\Simple-Batch\
but what I was expecting is

target\Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\modules\Simple-Batch\

I don't understand why this extra directory is created Simple-Batch again... Thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: Can you try adding _<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>_?

Comment: Just check `<outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../Server-Dist/target/Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bin/Server-Dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/modules/</outputDirectory>` looks like the problem. Furthermore it's not a good idea to create outside your own module.